# XML parsing with a root level element

Tags: xml, go, xml-parsing

Is it possible to parse root level XML elements?

This XML is without any wrapper `<message att='Hello'/>`

```
var x = Xml{}
xml.Unmarshal([]byte(`<message att='Hello'/>`), &x)
fmt.Println(x)
```

Xml Struct

```
type Xml struct {
    Message struct {
        Att string `xml:"att,attr"`
    } `xml:"message"`
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this. Simply remove the wrapping `Xml` element and unmarshal `Message` directly:

```
type Message struct {
    Att string `xml:"att,attr"`
}
```

```
var x = Message{}
err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(`<message att='Hello'/>`), &x)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(x)
```

https://play.golang.org/p/EdtaWLm6Cl